# Unable to get my ContentEntity base field definition to appear as checkboxes

Tags: 8, entities

I am trying to implement a base field with multiple selections as checkboxes I have had a go at implementing it but it stills appears as a select even after clearing the cache. I'm sure I'm doing this wrong but this is what I have:

```
$fields['content_display'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('list_integer')
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'type' => 'checkboxes',
    'weight' => -4,
  ))
  ->setSetting('allowed_values', $values)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `options_buttons` because this is the ID if the [OptionsButtonsWidget](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldWidget%21OptionsButtonsWidget.php/class/OptionsButtonsWidget/8.2.x) widget.

```
$fields['content_display'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('list_integer')
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'type' => 'options_buttons',
    'weight' => -4,
  ))
  ->setSetting('allowed_values', $values)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
```

Comment: Great that worked just had to set my cardinality to unlimited